# How to fix sepolicy error in android emulator (goldfish kernel + android-9) boot loop

Tags: android, build, android-emulator, android-source, android-kernel

I want to run custom kernel ( goldfish ) on android-9 (API 28) avd. 
So I just downloaded goldfish kernel:

```
    git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/ -b android-4.4
    make x86_64_ranchu_defconfig
    make -j4
```

then I run emulator :

```
   emulator -avd test -kernel goldfish/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -show-kernel
```

But there is some error between my kernel and SELinux policy of vendor. 
Here the logs:

```
[    1.170669] init: init first stage started!
[    1.172289] init: Using Android DT directory /sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/
[    1.174652] init: First stage mount skipped (missing/incompatible fstab in device tree)
[    1.176724] init: Skipped setting INIT_AVB_VERSION (not in recovery mode)
[    1.178464] init: Loading SELinux policy
[    1.182955] init: No precompiled sepolicy: No such file or directory
[    1.184557] init: Compiling SELinux policy
[    1.185672] init: Failed to read /vendor/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy_vers.txt: No such file or directory
[    1.188030] init: Unable to load SELinux policy
[    1.189192] init: Reboot start, reason: reboot, rebootTarget: bootloader
```

Obviously the system go in boot loop. 
How can I fix this?